# My sharepoint workflow in SharePoint Designer starts automatically everytime list is edited

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Hope some of you can help me, since I can't get my workflow to work properly.

I have created a workflow in a list, that is updated frequently. The purpose of the workflow is that when a status field is changed to the status "ongoing" and another value equals something (not relevant to my question) an email is sent. My problem is that, as said, the list is updated frequently and this means that every time the list is changed, the workflow starts because the status still equals "ongoing". I have tried to stop the workflow from starting using a boolean, as you can see in the attached screenshot - but it continues to start. What am I doing wrong? Hope you can help me. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2psV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make *infrastatusmailsent*, a field instead of variable. And everytime the workflow starts, check the value. If *infrastatusmailsent* is not set to "Yes" then send email and then update to "Yes" and save it to list.

I hope this helps.